# The correct pointer to a D3D11device vtable

Tags: c++, directx, comobject

How do I get a pointer to the vtable in this:

```
ID3D11Device *dev;          //the pointer to the device interface
```

This is what I have right now and I don't think it's right.

```
uintptr_t* pInterfaceVTable = *(uintptr_t**)dev;
```

If it is, then how do I get the member functions?  Again, this is what I have right now.

```
uintptr_t** g_deviceFunctionAddresses = new uintptr_t*[D3D11_DEVICE_METHOD_COUNT];
if(dev != NULL && swapchain != NULL){
    for(int i=0; i<D3D11_DEVICE_METHOD_COUNT; i++){
        g_deviceFunctionAddresses[i] = (uintptr_t*)pInterfaceVTable[i];
    }
    smplvtablefunction = pInterfaceVTable[functionoffset];
}
```

I've been stuck for a while on this.

Comment: `DWORD* vt = *reinterpret_cast<DWORD**>(dev);` Each index is one function (4 byte pointer) in 32-bit programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vtable is defined in the header as `ID3D11DeviceVtbl`.  You need to #include d3d11.h as a C header though, otherwise you get the class definition with a hidden vtable.

Comment: A few related questions:

1. Is there some type of walkthrough for this?

2. Is there a syntax that will just give me the address of a function instead of calling it like `d3d11dev->checkcounter();` will?